# Looking for responses to one specific tweet

Tags: twitter

Is there any way to: given a tweet, view all its replies?

I would prefer to do it from twitter.com, but if there is any other 3rd party service that helps, it's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the date of the tweet. Then wait for the tweet to load and then scroll down. You should see all the replies to that tweet. But there are some exceptions. Here's an example tweet where there's supposedly 1 reply but I don't see any:
[image]

My guess is perhaps the person who replied is someone I don't follow and have set their tweets to be protected in their privacy and safety settings.