# Does Twitter not show some replies?

Tags: twitter

I made [this tweet](https://twitter.com/andrewjgrimm/status/549112476516630528) in response to [someone else's tweet](https://twitter.com/DrMarranci/status/549097111552139264), but when I view his tweet directly (that is, going to the URL of that specific tweet), mine isn't visible, even after scrolling to the bottom.

AFAIK, he isn't blocking me, because I can follow him. Obviously, I'm not muting myself.

I suspect some other replies are not visible either, based on the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of conversation]

Does Twitter sometimes not show some replies?

Comment: Related http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11913/looking-for-responses-to-one-specific-tweet